# How to link one staff to multiple service she can offer using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to understand how I can possibly link 1 staff row to all the services that staff can offer.
 - Staff can offer multiple services.
 - Services are assigned to multiple staff.

I know about foreign key but from what I know it can only link to 1 row in a foreign table. I tried to search for an array that could contain multiple foreign keys and it doesn't exists.

How can I possibly assign example:
-staff1 provides: service1, service3.
and -staff 2 provides: service2, service3.

How can I do it in a good architecture?

thank you so much for your time and help it is very appreciated!

[image]

Comment: A `staff_id, service_id` composite primary key as a joining table. Then the combination of staff_id and service_id is unique rather than them individually being unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a many-to-many relationship between your `staff` and `service` tables. Here's how you do that.

Create a so-called *join* table. It will have this structure.

```
CREATE TABLE staff_service (
  service_id INT NOT NULL,
  staff_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (service_id, staff_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX staff_service (staff_id, service_id)
);
```

When there's a row in this table, it means that staff member provides that service. So, when a staff member starts to offer a service, INSERT a row in the table. When a staff member stops offering the service, DELETE the row.

There are two indexes in my suggested table definition. That's so lookups in both directions can take advantage of indexes.

This is the canonical way of using SQL-based RDBMSs to handle many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, it worked as planned. I get an error on the line UNIQUE INDEX (syntax error at or near "INDEX") I don't really know why but even without that line it doesn't allow me to make duplicates so I guess it works correctely. 

I also added foreign keys for the staff_id and service_id

Thank you so much :D

Comment: Doh. Smacks forehead. I used a MySQL tool to verify my CREATE TABLE. (sorry, I didn't see `postgresql` . The reverse index doesn't need to be UNIQUE to get its benefits.